# Updating one database with another database on insert, update or delete event in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have written a ruby on rails application. Here I am using one model like that:

```
class teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
 self.table_name = "teachers"
end
```

The teachers table get populated by another independent application. In my application I am using redis to store some specific data about teachers. The problem is that initially I have populated the redis with data from teachers table with the help of a rake task.

But whenever any insert, update or delete happens to teachers table the redis data becomes inconsistent. So I want whenever any save or update occurs in teachers table, the data also gets stored in redis, I mean some event or interrupt based kind of thing. Can I do that in my application without changing the other application that I have already mentioned, where the teachers data is actually stored? If possible, please give some idea.

Comment: sorry about the bad answer. Sounds like you just need to run the rake task every 5 mins and resync the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you weren't using Redis, I'd have recommended using an `after_save` callback (triggers each time model is saved -- created / updated):

```
#app/models/teacher.rb
Class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_save :update

    def update
        Model.create({attr: self.value})
    end
end
```

However, since you're using Redis, you need to synchronise the data cross-channel. I'd probably still use `after_save`, but with logic to determine which Redis values to update

Comment: But is that possible in case the model i.e. teacher in our case is saved in another application? I mean how the save will be triggered in my application. If I am wrong, please clarify.